# I can play once my level and I can't do the other. Array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

when I play the lvl1 my Array build normally, but if I want to do an other level after, nothing build. If I want to do an other level, even if I don't do the lvl1, only the first 5 column of my Array are build. And, to finish, when I finish the timer, I have this bug :

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at projsolo_fla::MainTimeline/collisions()[projsolo_fla.MainTimeline::frame3:133]
```

this is my frame 1 code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//--- Variables: ---

var toucheA: Boolean = false;
var toucheZ: Boolean = false;
var toucheE: Boolean = false;
var toucheR: Boolean = false;
var toucheT: Boolean = false;

var map:Sprite=new Sprite();

//--- Ecouteurs: ---

stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, pressee);
stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, relachee);
btnLevel.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, menuLevel);


//--- autre: ---
stop();

stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN; 
stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;  
stage.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, moove);

//--- Fonction: ---

function pressee (e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    switch (e.keyCode){
        case 65 :
            toucheA=true;
            Pac.y=55;
            break;

        case 90 :
            toucheZ=true;
            Pac.y=105;
            break;

        case 69 :
            toucheE=true;
            Pac.y=155;
            break;

        case 82 :
            toucheR=true;
            Pac.y=205;
            break;

        case 84 :
            toucheT=true;
            Pac.y=255;
            break;

        default :
            break;
    }
}

function relachee (e:KeyboardEvent):void{
    switch (e.keyCode){
        case 65 :
            toucheA=false;
            break;

        case 90 :
            toucheZ=false;
            break;

        case 69 :
            toucheE=false;
            break;

        case 82 :
            toucheR=false;
            break;

        case 84 :
            toucheT=false;
            break;

        default :
            break;
    }
}

function moove (e:Event):void{
    map.x-=5;
}

function menuLevel (e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop (2);
}
```

this is my frame 2 code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

btnMusique1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, playLVL1);
btnMusique2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, playLVL2);
btnMusique3.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, playLVL3);
btnMusique4.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, playLVL4);

function playLVL1 (e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop (3);
    lvl1 ();
}

function playLVL2 (e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop (3);
    lvl2();
}

function playLVL3 (e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop (3);
    lvl3();
}

function playLVL4 (e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(3);
    lvl4();
}
```

this is my frame 3 code:

```
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.sampler.NewObjectSample;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.BlockProgression;

//--- Variables: ---
stop();

var timer1: Timer=new Timer (70000,1);

var points: Number = 0;

stage.addChild(map);

var tableau1: Array=[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1],
                     [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],                         
                     [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],
                     [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1]];

var tableau2: Array=[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],
                     [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
                     [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],
                     [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0]];

var tableau3: Array=[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                     [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1]];

var tableau4: Array=[[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                     [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1],
                     [0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                     [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1],
                     [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1]];


var L:int=0;
var C:int=0;

// création du tableau.

function lvl1 () {
    for (L=0; L<tableau1.length ;L++){                          
        for(C=0; C<tableau1[1].length ;C++){                    
            if (tableau1[L][C]==1){
                var Block: block=new block();   
                    map.addChild(Block);
                    Block.name="Block_"+L+"_"+C;
                    Block.x=1620+C*60;
                    Block.y=55+L*50;    
                    Block.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, collisions);
                    stage.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, lvl1);
            }
        }
    }
}

function lvl2 () {
    for (L=0; L<tableau2.length;L++){
        for(C=0; C<tableau2.length;C++){
            if (tableau2[L][C]==1){
                var Block: block=new block();
                map.addChild(Block);
                Block.name="Block_"+L+"_"+C;
                Block.x=1620+C*60;
                Block.y=55+L*50;
                Block.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, collisions);
                stage.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, lvl2);
            }
        }
    }
}

function lvl3 () {
    for (L=0; L<tableau3.length;L++){
        for(C=0; C<tableau3.length;C++){
            if (tableau3[L][C]==1){
                var Block: block=new block();
                map.addChild(Block);
                Block.name="Block_"+L+"_"+C;
                Block.x=1620+C*60;
                Block.y=55+L*50;
                Block.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, collisions);
                stage.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, lvl3);
            }
        }
    }
}

function lvl4 () {
    for (L=0; L<tableau4.length;L++){
        for(C=0; C<tableau4.length;C++){
            if (tableau4[L][C]==1){
                var Block: block=new block();
                map.addChild(Block);
                Block.name="Block_"+L+"_"+C;
                Block.x=1620+C*60;
                Block.y=55+L*50;
                Block.addEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, collisions);
                stage.removeEventListener (Event.ENTER_FRAME, lvl4);
            }
        }
    }
}

//--- Ecouteurs: ---

timer1.addEventListener (TimerEvent.TIMER, stoplvl1);
timer1.start();

//--- Fonctions: ---

function stoplvl1 (e:TimerEvent) :void{
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moove);
    for (L=0; L<tableau1.length ;L++){                          
        for(C=0; C<tableau1[1].length ;C++){                    
            if (tableau1[L][C]==1){
                tableau1[L][C]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    stage.removeChild(map);
    gotoAndStop(4);
}

function collisions (e:Event):void {
    if(e.target.hitTestObject(Pac)){
        for (L=0; L<tableau1.length ;L++){                          
            for(C=0; C<tableau1[1].length ;C++){                    
                if (tableau1[L][C]==1){
                    tableau1[L][C]=0;
                }
            }
        }   
        e.target.nextFrame();
        e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collisions);
        points+=1000;
        Scorelvl.text = points.toString();
    }
}
```

and this is my frame 4 code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

ScoreFin.text = points.toString();

btnMenu.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, retourMenu);

function retourMenu (e:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

**EDIT**
As per OP's comment:

I have my different levels (`LVL2`,`LVL3`,`LVL4`) that is not correctly initialized when I execute my function `lvl2`, `lvl3`, `lvl4` in the loop ranging from `frame 3` from `line 64 to 110`.

Instead of creating the array this creates only the first five columns, and not the rest.

Comment: Lot of code, no clear error. This way, it is unlikely to get help quick. Try to locate the source of your problems, and ask specific questions please.

Comment: My pincipal problem is that I can't play all the level and I can't replay a lvl after play one. Only my lvl1 build correctly...

Comment: It is of no use to repeat what you included in the question. The problem is, that `level, lvl1, replaying` are words from _your_ problem domain. They are not part of the common terms of programming, and I'd have to read through your 200 lines of code to understand their meaning. Nobody will do that. You have to "translate" them to be understood by a programmer unfamiliar with your code, something like this: "I have a <type> that is not correctly initialized when I execute <specified part> in the loop ranging from <line> to <line>. Instead of <expected> this happens: <bad behaviour>"

Comment: Ok, I try, sorry. I have my differents level (LVL2,LVL3,LVL4) that is not correctly initialized when I execute my function lvl2, lvl3, lvl4 in the loop ranging from frame 3 from line 64 to 110. Instead of create my array this happens create only the first five column.

Answer (score 1):

One: You have hardcoded `tableau1` in all your functions below level creation, including `collisions`.

Two: You erase `tableau1` on hittest event.

Three: Your `Pac` object is undefined if your current frame is not 3, as the layout is written as keyframes, but you don't remove ALL the listeners that target `Pac`, only the one that's attached to the colliding block.

And four: When you build the array, its length is 5, but you iterate both row and column from 0 to length-1, causing your level to have only 5 columns. Instead, you need to run the inner cycle until `tableau1[0].length`, like you do in `collisions`.

You really need to learn to debug your code, and to trace what is called and from where.

Comment: I need to create a function 'collisions' for each Array ?

Comment: No, you need an extra array with data that will be filled in `lvl1()` and other level generation functions, and then used in `collisions` and other functions.

Comment: Thanks but, I don't understand what I have to put in the extra array :/ what I have to do with this extra array .